# Webpack 5 will not load animated gif file

Tags: javascript, html, dom, gif, webpack-5

I am new to webpack but following along with the official docs: https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#setup

I am trying to load an animated gif using webpack 5.

The placehodler for the gif is loading but the console error is:
"GET file:///home/jordan/repos/KrabbShack/dist/[object%20HTMLParagraphElement] net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
[object%20HTMLParagraphElement]:1 "

When I run the build I get this error:
ERROR in ./src/assets/krabbyPatty.gif 1:6
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.

My gif file path src/assets/krabbyPatty.gif

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/template.html')
    })
  ]
};
```

Module I am working in home.js path:./src/home.js

```
import KrabbyPatty from './assets/krabbyPatty.gif';
```

```
function createContent() {
    const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    const slogan = document.createElement('p');
    newDiv.classList.add('content')
    slogan.textContent = 'Home of the beloved Krabby Patty';
    const patty = new Image(325, 325)
    patty.src = {KrabbyPatty}
    newDiv.appendChild(slogan);
    newDiv.appendChild(patty);

    return newDiv;
}
```

I also tried:

```
    const patty = document.createElement('img');
    patty.src = krabbyPatty;
```

I have tried not wrapping in curly brackets like the official docs and with brackets.I attempted to just use img literal and write the html inside of backticks but I probably did that wrong and I'd prefer to learn why the official doc method is not working for me.

P.S. This is my first question, please forgive me if my format is wrong, I am open to constructive criticism. I searched for other questions regarding this but all i found were methods prior to webpack 5 with solutions such as url-loader which also failed and from my reading is not necessary with webpack 5.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found was in the webpack.config.js file, adding a generator to the module rule:

```
{
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
        type: 'asset/resource',
        generator: {
          filename: 'images/[name][ext]'
       }
      },
```